# Visual Studio: Inconsistency in method header

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a method in C++:

```
HRESULT Foo(const ULONG bar, const ULONG baz, ODP& odp)
```

ODP is typedef'd to `unsigned short`.

When I call this method, I get a VS runtime check error when the calling method ends: "The stack around `odp` is corrupted."

When I look at the method being called, and hover my mouse, VS pops up this description:

```
Foo(const unsigned long, const const unsigned long, const unsigned short * const)
```

Why the inconsistency? Why the two `const`s for the middle param? Why isn't the last param `ODP&`?

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you don't have two different definitions for `Foo` or `ODP`. If one definition is seen in one context and another somewhere else, you enter the land of undefined behavior.

Comment: +1. More precisely: It is probable the caller of Foo sees Foo as `Foo(..., const unsigned short * const)`, while of course, inside Foo, the prototype is `Foo(..., unsigned short &)`, so the search for inconsistency should start at the file containing the "caller" code. And if this file is a header, then the search is all the more complex...

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer: the VS debugger is getting its info from the machine code, not from the source.